# Python nested for loop to match strings in array elements to a file

Tags: python, file, for-loop, python-2.7, nested-loops

The purpose of my code is to iterate over each element in an array, convert the element to a string, and return lines from another file that contain this string. My code is:

```
    for element in myarray:
         elementstring=''.join(element)
         for line in myfile:
              if elementstring in line:
                  print line
```

If the code is run, it will only work for the first element. Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: What is `myfile`? Is it a file object or an array of strings?

Comment: myfile is a file object, that is opened with myfile=open('location','r')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because when you read through the lines of a file once, you reach the end of the file and there are no lines left to read. You need to close the file and re-open it for reading for each `element`.

Here's one way of doing that:

```
for element in myarray:
    elementstring=''.join(element)
    with open('path/to/myfile') as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            if elementstring in line:
                print line
```

Alternatively, if this is a small enough file, you can reduce the runtime by avoiding several `read`s from disk by caching the lines in the file before hand like so:

```
myfile = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('path/to/myfile')]
for element in myarray:
    elementstring=''.join(element)
    for line in myfile:
        if elementstring in line:
            print line
```

Comment: The first example is problematic as it does not close the file and so the OS related resources are not released. Consider using the with statement or manually closing the file after the for loop.

Comment: ah yes the first example worked perfectly! Thank you very much inspector gadget. Also Dunes, thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @Dunes: Edited to fix with `with`. That should kill the file pointer at the end of the loop

Answer (score 0):

you go through a file... that moves the pointer to the end ... you need to reopen the file or `myfile.seek(0)` ... but there are some other issues with your code.  and its hard to answer without seeing `myarray`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Myarray is: [['IGHV1-18*01'], ['IGHV1-18*02'], ['IGHV1-18*03']]

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(myfile) as f:
    lines=[x for x in f] #store all lines in a list first
    for element in myarray:    #now iterate over myarray
         elementstring=''.join(element)
         for line in lines:            #now iterate over individual line from lines
              if elementstring in line:
                  print line
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, a file is not a collection. A file is read sequentially, and you need to use the seek function to get back to the first line on every iteration.

Anyway, this is not exactly the best way to do what you want.

Reading from a file is usually slower than reading from RAM (even with cache), so it's better to have the main loop going through the file.

It's also better to compute all the string values on an external array beforehand.

Finally, there are lots of algorithms for searching a set of strings in a file (or a bigger string) which you might consider.

Here's an optimized version of your code:

```
strs = [' '.join(element) for element in myarray]
for line in open(''path/to/myfile'):
    for elementstring in strs:
         if elementstring in line:
              print line
```